# How can I install npm dependencies manually using meteor

Tags: meteor, npm, meteorite

I need to **install npm dependencies** described on my packages.json file **manually** (by manually I mean with a command like `npm install` or `mrt install`, that doesn't require to start the app).

I know that `meteor-npm` creates the npm directory inside packages and that when I start the app using `mrt` or `meteor` the npm modules get downloaded.

But I'm writing a test script and I need the modules to be installed before running the tests so I would need to install them as I install standard meteorite modules with `mrt install`.

Comment: Why don't you just use Tinytest, which installs the npm modules for you using the same build process?

Comment: Do you have a link to tinytest? how does it connect with my existing tests?

Comment: Tinytest is Meteor's built-in testing framework: https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/meteor-testing-packages-with-tinytest. It's not the final solution, but all of Meteor's internal packages are written with it and you can take inspiration from there. It also can be integrated with Travis CI: https://github.com/arunoda/travis-ci-meteor-packages.

Comment: I don't think tinytest is a good fit beacuse (I didn't mention it) I'm doing some functional tests with webDriverJS

Answer (score 0):

In theory this is very easy, because you could just run `npm install PACKAGENAME` in your project directory. However, this would of course mess up meteor, which will try to interpret the new files as meteor files.

Instead, you have two options:

1. install in a super directory (they will be found): `cd .. && npm install PACKAGENAME`
2. install packages globally: `npm install -g PACKAGENAME`

Comment: I think this could work but does not fit in my case, because I would have to keep a duplicated register of my npm modules (because I'm trying to automatize this on a shell script)